# Not able to set header for content type request in spray

Tags: scala, spray

A piece of my code to validate user login is :

```
val loginRoute = path("login") {
    post {
      parameter('next ?) {
        (next) =>
          entity(as[FormData]) {
            params =>
              implicit ctx => {
                var headers = List[HttpHeader]()
                val user = params.fields.find(_._1 == "username").get._2
                val pass = params.fields.find(_._1 == "password").get._2
                val remember = params.fields.find(_._1 == "remember") match {
                  case Some(rem) => rem._2
                  case None => "off"
                }
                LdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(user, pass) match {
                  case false =>
                    sendResponse(StatusCodes.Forbidden.intValue, "Authentication Failed")
                    redirect("login", StatusCodes.Found)
                  case true =>
                    if ("on".equalsIgnoreCase(remember)) {
                      val hash = calculateHash(Map(Const.USERNAME -> user))
                      headers = List(HttpHeaders.`Set-Cookie`(HttpCookie(Const.COOKIE_REMEMBER_ME_KEY, user)),
                        HttpHeaders.`Set-Cookie`(HttpCookie(Const.COOKIE_AUTH_HASH, hash)))
                    }
                    val url = next match {
                      case Some(path) => path
                      case None => "/"
                    }
                    complete {
                      HttpResponse(
                        status = StatusCodes.Found,
                        headers = Location(url) :: headers,
                        entity = StatusCodes.Found.htmlTemplate match {
                          case "" ⇒ HttpEntity.Empty
                          case template ⇒ HttpEntity(`text/html`, template format url)
                        }
                      )
                    }
                }
              }
          }

      }
    }
  }
```

However I am not able to set the request content Type. Shouldn't spray do that for me automatically? My request will be of

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Which I am setting in my POST request header . 
However I am still getting :

```
There was a problem with the requests Content-Type:
Expected 'application/json'
```

Please help me out here ! Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are probably several issues in your code. The cause for "Expected 'application/json'" is likely that you use one the json support traits (not shown in your example) like LiftJsonSupport or Json4sSupport which will be attempted to be used for the `entity(as[FormData])`.

Comment: The solution to this problem is to use the `formFields` directives instead of `entity(as[FormData])`. See http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/form-field-directives/formFields/.

Comment: The next issue will be your usage of `implicit ctx =>` which will very likely not do what you expect it to do. Your usage of LdapAuthenticationProvider also seems a bit off, as well of the manual construction of (error) responses which isn't necessary usually. I would suggest you post your example on the spray mailing list at http://groups.google.com/group/spray-user, if possible with a description of what you try to achieve, so we can work from there on the remaining issues.

Comment: If you want to solve it yourself, start from the outside and remove all the inner directives and replace them with simple debug `complete` routes to make sure one level of functionality works before adding and fixing inner stuff. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as Jrudolf suggested was that my JSON support trait was trying to deserialize the data. The headers were being ignored. Infact it was not even getting there. The solution was as simple as extending the already existing marshallers.

```
    class LoginServlet(context: akka.actor.ActorRefFactory) extends BaseServlet with FormDataUnmarshallers {
}
```